# How to change the Text color for a subtree in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

I want that every `Text` inside a particular `Widget` will have a white color, although they all can have different sizes. I know I can change every singe `Text` to have a white color, but I want to make it smart and change the Theme for that particular `Widget`.

I tried this:

```dart
DefaultTextStyle.merge(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Text 1',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
      ),
      Text('Text 2')
    ],
  ),
),
```

The problem is `Text 1` becomes black and `Text 2` is white as I wanted.

I thought that using `DefaultTextStyle.merge` I would still be able to use `Theme.of(context)` to get the general `TextTheme`, still maintaining the changes over `DefaultTextStyle` but apparently I am wrong.

What's the correct way of changing a sub-tree's text color, while being able to access the rest of the original `Theme`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that you are overwriting the `style` using this `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title`, it's getting the `title` style from `textTheme` from you the current `Theme` of your app.

A possible solution is to use a custom style but copying the color property, like this :

```
DefaultTextStyle(
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Text 1',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.copyWith(
                        color: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.color),
                  ),
                  Text('Text 2')
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

The easy way is just not using the `textTheme` from your `Theme`, just write your own style without specifying the color, like this:

```
DefaultTextStyle(
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Text 1',
                //change the style without changing the color
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
              ),
              Text('Text 2')
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**UPDATE**

I found another way what you can use :

```
Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
                  bodyColor: Colors.white,
                  displayColor: Colors.white,
                ),
          ),
          child: DefaultTextStyle(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Text 1',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    ),
                    Text('Text 2')
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

If you don't want to use the `Builder` widget, use the `Theme.of(context).copyWith`   on the parent widget (of your statelesswidget/statefulwidget).

Comment: So there's no way to override part of a Theme for a subtree in a transparent way? It looks cumbersome to use a `Builder` and then deal with `Theme` and `DefaultTextStyle` at the same time

Comment: And why aren't you using `DefaultTextStyle.merge()`?

Comment: Actually, you can use DefaultTextStyle.merge too.

Comment: Another way is to wrap your widget inside Theme, then overwrite the TextTheme and set the same color for all of the styles inside textTheme

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler, in my use case it will be simpler to just set the color to white on each Text. I guess Flutter could improve this.

Comment: the issue with `Theme.of(context).textTheme.title`, is that value comes with the color of your main `Theme`

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was hoping there was a way to define the color and all the typography themes would update accordingly.

Comment: This looks a lot more interesting... But do you need to define the white color inside the `Theme` and again inside the `DefaultTextStyle`?

Comment: yes, that's a little weird, if you test the code and remove `DefaultTextStyle`, it won't work for the last `Text` widget (because it doesn't have style),  but it works on the first.

Comment: I see... I will open a feature request for having a simpler way of achieving this.